# Java Insertion Sort doesnt sort

Tags: java, sorting

I have written a java sorting algorithm by insertion, the code compiles but doesnt sort:(. If anyone could point out any flaws, Id be very thankful, Java doesnt...

```
public class Sort {

public static int[] sort(int[] x) {
    int[] y = new int[x.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < x.length; ++i) {
        int j = 0;
        while (y[j] < x[i] && j < i) ++j;
        for (int k = i-1; k >= j; --k) y[k+1] = y[k];
        y[j]=x[i];
    }   
    return y;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] size = new int[10];
    for(int k=0; k<size.length; ++k ) {
        size[k]=(int)(Math.random()*20);
        System.out.println(size[k]);
    }
    System.out.println(sort(size));
}}
```

Comment: Thats the output on the console btw: ```7
11
15
12
17
8
1
8
17
2
[I@39ed3c8d
```    so the unsorted Array and then just random...

Comment: For starters, "while (y[j] < x[i]" references y while y has not been loaded.  Your "find insertion point" code should default to 0.  The order of boolean expressions protects against things like this, like saying "x != null && x.y > 0" protects x.y from a null x reference.

Comment: Everyone is answering about your sysout, but those aren't real solutions. I would recommend just using `Arrays.toString()` to pretty print your array. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(int[])

Answer (score 2):

`[I@39ed3c8d` is returned by invoking `toString()` on an int array, which you then print with `System.out.println`.

You presumably want `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sort(size)));` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the reference of size i.e., `[I@39ed3c8d` .

This should help you to understand:

```
public class Sort {

public static int[] sort(int[] x) {
    int[] y = new int[x.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < x.length; ++i) {
        int j = 0;
        while (y[j] < x[i] && j < i) ++j;
        for (int k = i-1; k >= j; --k) y[k+1] = y[k];
        y[j]=x[i];
    }   
    return y;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] size = new int[10];
    System.out.println("Befor sorting");
    for(int k=0; k<size.length; ++k ) {
        size[k]=(int)(Math.random()*20);
        System.out.print(size[k]);
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    size = sort(size);

    System.out.println("\nAfter sorting");
    for(int i = 0; i<size.length; i++){
        System.out.print(size[i]);
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

That random  is result of:
`System.out.println(sort(size));`

Do this instead:

```
size = sort(size);
   for(int k=0; k<size.length; ++k ) {
    
    

 System.out.print(size[k] + " " );
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(int[])